# MSSQL nvarchar A contains nvarchar B

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got two tables. In Table1 there's a nvarchar A and in Table2 nvarchar B which is a part of nvarchar A like showed below.

```
    Table1
nvarcharA
    'This is super test sample'

    Table 2
nvarcharB
    'super'
```

What I'm trying to do is list all records from Table 2 that are occuring in any record from Table1.

I already tried:

```
select CHARINDEX(nvarcharB, nvarcharA) as A from Table1
```

or

```
select nvarcharA from Table1
where exists (select nvarcharB from Table2)
```

Sadly none of this works. There's no ID to bound them in join statement.

Anyone knows useful solution?

Comment: Move the `CHARINDEX` part to where clause and check > 0.

Comment: Sorry but that's not working as intended. I don't see how's that a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for something like this:

```
select t2.*
from Table2 t2
where exists (select 1
              from Table1 t1
              where t1.col like '%' + t2.col + '%'
             );
```

Comment: What if col contains `%` or other wildcards?

Comment: probably works, unless you need the `ESCAPE` clause (don't mention the performance.)

Comment: This works like a charm, only Table1 has almost 3mln rows so performance is quite low but I can handle that with indexes and so. I've got one more question, what happens when there're more then one column in Table2? Is it checking if all columns exists in Table2 or any column from Table1 exist in Table2? Thanks

Comment: @n0rek . . . This column uses `exists`, so you can have more than one condition in the `where`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff right I saw that after posting question :) Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

if you purely want to get results from Table1 if there is a match in Table2
you could "simply" use the Like statement in your join

you could end up with the following:

```
    SELECT 
      nvarcharA,
      nvarcharB
    from [Table 1] 
    inner join [table 2]
               ON [table 1].nvarcharA like '%' + [table 2].nvarcharB + '%'
```

You could play around with the variables used in the like statement. (weither or not it should start, end or as in the example anywhere in the data.